# Search and replace specific terms in different df

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs with a series of terms that represent an emotion (eg anger, happiness) and I need to iterate through all the lines of another df looking for lines that contain some of the terms in the series and exchange their value for the emotion name that the term represents, or add another value (eg None) if neither term matches one present in the two df.

I'll try to explain it through the examples below:

```
# Two df2 with target terms:

anger = pd.DataFrame({'anger': ['Angry','Acerbic', 'Aggressive', 'Bitter', 'Fiery', 'Outraged', 'Rebellious', 'Snide']})

happiness= pd.DataFrame({'happiness':['Happy','Cheerful','Bright', 'Celebratory', 'Effervescent', 'Gleeful', 'Humorous', 
                              'Irreverent', 'Rambunctious', 'Raucous', 'Rollicking', 'Silly', 'Sweet', 'Whimsical', 'Witty', 'Joyous']
})
```

Df target:

| moods |
| --- |
| Aggressive, Literate, Rebellious, Fun |
| Boisterous, Bright, Acerbic, Silly |

Expected df:

| moods |
| --- |
| Anger, None, Anger, None |
| None, Happiness, Anger, Happiness |

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A pretty much brute force way I can think of is create a function to replace a given word (silly) with the corresponding feeling (anger) and then use df.apply to apply that function on all the rows (can use .split()) to split each row into multiple words. But I'm not sure how efficient this would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
# Create patterns
anger_pat = fr"\b({'|'.join(anger['anger'])})\b"
happiness_pat = fr"\b({'|'.join(happiness['happiness'])})\b"

# Replace patterns
df['moods'] = df['moods'].replace({anger_pat: 'Anger',
                                   happiness_pat: 'Happiness',
                                   r'\b(?!Anger|Happiness\b)\w+': 'None'}, 
                                  regex=True)
```

As the `replace` function is executed sequentially, the previous substitutions are already made. So, the last pattern means 'if the word is not 'Anger' or 'Happiness' replace it by 'None'.

Output:

```
>>> df
                               moods
0           Anger, None, Anger, None
1  None, Happiness, Anger, Happiness

>>> print(anger_pat)
\b(Angry|Acerbic|Aggressive|Bitter|Fiery|Outraged|Rebellious|Snide)\b

>>> print(happiness_pat)
\b(Happy|Cheerful|Bright|Celebratory|Effervescent|Gleeful|Humorous|Irreverent|Rambunctious|Raucous|Rollicking|Silly|Sweet|Whimsical|Witty|Joyous)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the `anger`/`happiness` dataframes together, `.explode` the target df and `.merge` them. Then, `.groupby` them back:

```py
x = (
    pd.concat([anger.stack(), happiness.stack()])
    .to_frame(name="moods")
    .droplevel(0)
    .reset_index()
)
df["moods"] = df["moods"].str.split(", ")
df = df.explode("moods").reset_index()

print(
    df.merge(x, on="moods", how="left")
    .fillna("None")
    .groupby("index_x")["index_y"]
    .agg(", ".join)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .to_frame(name="moods")
)
```

Prints:

```
                               moods
0           anger, None, anger, None
1  None, happiness, anger, happiness
```